# Copying files into Dropbox folder from command line

Tags: batch

I made the following code.
Since it is a Batch, any kind of problems can appear.
Please review it and point any problems when copying files into Dropbox!
Its intent is that you will copy a file into an Dropbox folder.
Its syntax is `dropbox <files-to-dropbox> <dropbox-folder-to-copy-to>`.

```
@echo off
set dropbox=%userprofile%\dropbox
if exist %dropbox% (if not exist %dropbox%\%2 mkdir %dropbox%\%2) else (echo Get Dropbox for PC before using this!)
if exist %dropbox%\%2 copy %1 %dropbox%\%2
@echo on
```

It would have been cool to use the `dropbox` tag as well, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script will be a lot easier to read if you expand the long statements to multiple lines:

```
@echo off
set dropbox=%userprofile%\dropbox
if exist %dropbox% (
    if not exist %dropbox%\%2 mkdir %dropbox%\%2
) else (
    echo Get Dropbox for PC before using this!
)
if exist %dropbox%\%2 copy %1 %dropbox%\%2
@echo on
```

Is that `@echo on` at the end necessary? Probably not, but I don't have a Windows with me to play around to verify.

The last `if` statement is pointless to execute if the first `if` statement was false. It would be better to move this inside the first if statement:

```
@echo off
set dropbox=%userprofile%\dropbox
if exist %dropbox% (
    if not exist %dropbox%\%2 mkdir %dropbox%\%2
    if exist %dropbox%\%2 copy %1 %dropbox%\%2
) else (
    echo Get Dropbox for PC before using this!
)
```

Possibly an even better way is to use the equivalent of an *early return*,
by leaving the main execution path when something is wrong.
You can do this using [`goto :eof`](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html).
After this the `else` statement can be flattened:

```
@echo off
set dropbox=%userprofile%\dropbox
if not exist %dropbox% (
    echo Get Dropbox for PC before using this!
    goto :eof
)
if not exist %dropbox%\%2 mkdir %dropbox%\%2
if exist %dropbox%\%2 copy %1 %dropbox%\%2
```

Rather than using the meaningless symbols `%1` and `%2` throughout the script,
it would be better to put these values to variables with descriptive names, for example:

```
@echo off
set source=%1
set target=%2
set dropbox=%userprofile%\dropbox
if exist %dropbox% (
    echo Get Dropbox for PC before using this!
    goto :eof
)
if not exist %dropbox%\%target% mkdir %dropbox%\%target%
if exist %dropbox%\%target% copy %source% %dropbox%\%target%
```

Comment: Great! I loved your work with the script. Though later I might try Python, because I'm very good at it.